# Manually timing out a request in Gatling

Tags: timeout, polling, gatling

I have a long-poll method in my application that will return a response either when a certain operation is completed (returns info about the op) or when it times out (configured server-side timeout).

I need to test it in Gatling in a way that while Gatling is waiting for the response, I can specify a timeout for the request so it will fail after that time passes if the request hasn't returned a response on its own.

E.g. the long poll's server-side timeout is 20 seconds and I want Gatling to stop waiting for the response and render the request as failed if 15 seconds have passed.

Is it at all possible? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and waiting for help from the community, I came up with my own solution.

I decided to rely on Gatling's HTTP request timeout (default 60 seconds). I even have two options, depending on the environment:

1) Leave the server long poll timeout configuration be (20 seconds) and configure the Gatling's timeout accordingly (e.g. 15 seconds). Other tests and requests will not be influenced by it in a fast testing environment.

2) Leave the Gatling's timeout be (60 seconds) and increase the server's long poll timeout configuration (e.g. 70 seconds). Then the other requests and tests will not be influenced in any environment.

Answer (score 0):

Above scenarios are easily possible Level , you can do like below to start with :-

```
 setUp(yourscenario.inject(atOnceUsers(Configuration.NO_OF_USERS))).maxDuration(Configuration.MAX_DURATION minutes);
```

Ref https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/simulation_setup/

Comment: Thank you, but I believe my case is too complex for this. It would be even more complex to refactor my simulation setups to accommodate this. And then it could only work if I increase all the timeouts (server, Gatling) so much that all my test environments could handle this (some are faster, some are slower). Otherwise it may happen that the scenario stops before it even reaches the long poll request as my scenarios consist of possibly long waits and other requests. I will try though.